# How can I create a reference that can contain both a stack and a list without needing a cast in c#?

Tags: c#, list, collections, stack

I'd like to be able to have a reference to a collection in a superclass that will need to contain either a stack or a list in a subclass, and I am having trouble understanding how to make that work, any ideas?

Something like:

```
public class Group 
{
     Collection<Human> group;
}

public class PeopleStack : Group
{
     public PeopleStack()
     {
           this.group  = new Stack<Human>();   
     }
} 

public class Crowd : Group
{
     public Crowd()
     {
           this.group  = new List<Human>();   
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean. Can you post a code example, like a [mre]?

Comment: ok, done, something like that, sorry first timer.

Comment: I guess you could change the Collection to the interface ICollection, but I don't really see what advantage you're getting at by doing this whole thing.

Comment: I tried that already, it didn't work, it told me I needed to cast the stack...

Comment: You could just forget about the stack and use `List<T>` everywhere. A list is very efficient when used as a stack. The implementation of `Stack` is actually a subset of the implementation of List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stack is defined as

```
public class Stack<T> : 
     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>, 
     System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection<T>, 
     System.Collections.ICollection
```

and the List is

```
public class List<T> : 
     System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>, 
     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>,
     System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>, 
     System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection<T>, 
     System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<T>, 
     System.Collections.IList
```

So you can use one of the strong (generic) types `IEnumerable<Human>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<Human>` for `group`.

And of course that should be `protected` etc, but I suppose you know that.